# What's a word for setting up a mechanism to prevent you from doing something in the future no matter what you may say or do then?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose I've a tough exam tomorrow and I plan to study all day. Knowing that I'm usually great at procrastinating, I ask my family members to keep a tab on me and to do whatever is necessary to bring me back to my books the whole day. And I tell them that they should not fail this duty even if I may, at a later time, ask them to stop doing this.

Or suppose I set up guards to keep me inside my home for the whole day no matter what I may tell them later. So when later that day I change my mind and wish to go outside, these guards will not let me out no matter how hard I try to make them stop doing it.

**Is there a specific name for such a situation?**

I've tried using *self-lock*, but that mostly has to do with physical locks that lock automatically. I tried *self-restraint*, but that means controlling my desires or avoiding falling into temptation, not exactly about setting up external factors to stop me in the future.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to [Mazura](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321638/whats-a-word-for-setting-up-a-mechanism-to-prevent-you-from-doing-something-in?noredirect=1#comment732313_321638), here's a [quote from Young Frankenstein](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072431/quotes?item=qt0484677) that serves as a better example:

> *No matter what you hear in there, no matter how cruelly I beg you, no matter how terribly I may scream, do not open this door or you will undo everything I have worked for. Do you understand? Do not open this door.*

Comment: How about 'failsafe'? "3. Guaranteed not to fail" (*American Heritage*). I suppose 'foolproof' is another option.

Comment: @JEL Maybe. Let me see if there are more suggestions. So is it a fail-safe if you ask a little sister to wake you up whenever you fall asleep while studying? And then this sister will not allow you to sleep even if you later decided you needed some sleep time.

Comment: If you're sure the little sister won't let you go to sleep, no matter what you say later, that's a failsafe (the noun means 'a failsafe mechanism').

Comment: Boxing yourself in. Painting yourself in a corner.

Comment: @JEL Post an answer. Maybe that is correct.

Comment: Another option might be 'safeguard'

Comment: @Dan I like that. But does it imply that **you** set it up against **yourself**?

Comment: @NVZ the word itself does not but maybe the context can? *I put certain safeguards into place to prevent blablabla...*

Comment: *No matter what you hear in there, no matter how cruelly I beg you, no matter how terribly I may scream, do not open this door or you will undo everything I have worked for. Do you understand? Do not open this door.*

Comment: @Mazura Wow, my thoughts exactly. I'm sure such quotes are popular in novels and films, but what is such a thing called?

Comment: @NVZ [No Matter How Much I Beg](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoMatterHowMuchIBeg) –TV-tropes

Comment: @Mazura In that link, they mention "self-restraint"

Comment: You're setting up an *enforced [quarantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarantine) protocol*, though your first example may also be popularly termed a [*fool's errand* or *snipe hunt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipe_hunt) since the participants cannot actually make you study if you actively resist.

Comment: I've heard "handcuff myself"

Comment: Or, although they don't quite convey the specific feeling as well, you might also consider just building off of "promise" and similar words; assure, pledge, guarantee, etc., which are basically contracts today to ensure some behavior in the future. "Bond" has a good tone of virtuous promissory constraint; "Having arranged my surroundings, I am now bound to complete..."

Comment: Similar concept (although not at all what you're describing) that came to my head when i saw this question is a [*dead-man's switch*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man%27s_switch), a device that is automatically bound to set off no matter input from the user if certain events happens (eg. when someone is no longer around to stop it from going off, or something along those lines).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd say you're talking about a **[Ulysses Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_pact)**:

*a freely made decision that is designed and intended to bind oneself in the future. The term is used in medicine, especially in reference to advance directives (also known as living wills), where there is some controversy over whether a decision made by a person in one state of health should be considered binding upon that person when he or she is in a markedly different, usually worse, state of health.*

*The term refers to the pact that Ulysses (Greek name "Ὀδυσσεύς", Odysseus) made with his men as they approached the Sirens. Ulysses wanted to hear the Sirens' song although he knew that doing so would render him incapable of rational thought. He put wax in his men's ears so that they could not hear, and had them tie him to the mast so that he could not jump into the sea. He ordered them not to change course under any circumstances, and to keep their swords upon him and to attack him if he should break free of his bonds. Upon hearing the Sirens' song, Ulysses was driven temporarily insane and struggled with all of his might to break free so that he might join the Sirens, which would have meant his death.*
( -- Wikipedia)

Comment: I really like this and am glad to know that there is a snappy name for the set-up. My only concern with this would be that it may not be commonly enough known to be of practical use if it also has to be explained in the text. though I'll be doing my best to make it more widely known now that *I* know it!

Comment: Following that link, it seems you can also refer to it as an "advance directive", or sometimes an "advance decision". The advantage is that the words will be easier for an unfamiliar person to interpret. The disadvantage is that a person with a law background may think you mean a "living will". Your best bet is to define whatever term you decide on.

Comment: Based on a literature search, "Ulysses Contract" is prevalent. "Ulysses Pact" is very rare.

Answer (score 8):

A 'failsafe' or a 'fail-safe plan' might best describe the situation you outline. The word does not itself denote or connote a reflexive sense, which would have to be supplied by the context of use. Sense 3 of the denotation of the adjective, from *American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language* (fifth edition), applies most directly to what I understand of the meaning you desire:

> **fail-safe** or **fail·safe**
>   *adj.*
>   1. Capable of compensating automatically and safely for a failure, as of a mechanism or power source.
>   2. Acting to discontinue a military attack on the occurrence of any of various predetermined conditions.
>   3. Guaranteed not to fail: *"There is no fail-safe mechanism guaranteed either to contain or to restore presidential authority" (Arthur M. Schlesinger, Jr.).*
>   *n.*
>   A fail-safe mechanism.

(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. S.v. "failsafe." Retrieved April 26 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/failsafe )

'Fool-proof' might be another option, but because you're applying the term to yourself I have reservations about recommending it to you:

> **fool·proof** *adj.*
>   1. Designed so as to be impervious to human incompetence, error, or misuse: *a foolproof detonator; a foolproof safety lock.*
>   2. Effective; infallible: *a foolproof scheme.*

(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. S.v. "foolproof." Retrieved April 26 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/foolproof )

Similar, but even more pronounced reservations come with any recommendation of the parallel term 'idiot-proof'. 'Idiot-proof' is used more informally than either 'foolproof' or 'failsafe':

> **id·i·ot-proof** *adj. Slang*
>   So easy to use or make that there is very little chance of failure: *"idiot-proof recipes that cut corners by making use of packaged foods" (Howie Rumberg).*

(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. S.v. "idiot-proof." Retrieved April 26 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idiot-proof )

Also note that, unlike 'failsafe', neither 'foolproof' nor 'idiot-proof' are used alone as nouns.

Comment: BTW, using _failsafe_ to mean "guaranteed not to fail" is a dreadful abuse of the word.  A mechanism is failsafe when its failure mode is in the safe direction.  For example, the brakes on large vehicles are designed so air-pressure is required to keep them _off_.  If an airhose or cylinder ruptures, the brake automatically applies itself and the vehicle slows or stops.  This is "failsafe" because a rupture is exponentially more likely than the pressure remaining high because of a malfunction and stopping a vehicle is far less likely to be dangerous than not-stopping it.

Answer (score 5):

The closest phrases I could think of for your scenario:

Your family members would be **keeping / holding you accountable** for your own studying.

You would be taking **preventive measures** to make sure you don't procrastinate.

Answer (score 4):

Though you may express the concept in many different  ways, I'd probably use the term ***[straightjacket](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/straitjacket)*** in a figurative sense:

> - something that ​severely ​limits ​development or ​activity in a way that is ​damaging:

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 4):

**Irrevocable**, as in "irrevocable directive" or "irrevocable order".

For example from [Grass Roots](https://books.google.com/books?id=OHg9pcIFQVQC&pg=PT397&dq=%22irrevocable%20order%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUruKW87PMAhUD1B4KHR5LCjM4FBDoAQgoMAI#v=onepage&q=%22irrevocable%20order%22&f=false) by Stuart Woods

> "I'm going to give you an irrevocable order.”
>
> “I would never allow anyone to revoke your orders, sir.”
>
> “I mean irrevocable, even by me. If I should weaken, you must be strong and carry out this assignment, regardless of anything further I have to say about it"

Comment: Closely similar to that is saying "this order **cannot be countermanded**, even by me".

Answer (score 3):

When a person is establishing such safeguards, you may say (in a quite formal manner) that:

> He is setting up **provisional self-protection measures**.

Answer (score 3):

"I am **binding myself** to study all day."

The origin of this phrase is probably related to the story of Ulysses/Odysseus and the Sirens, as related in JHCL's answer. The phrase "I am binding myself to the mast" makes that connection explicit. But the simple version of the phrase (with no mention of masts) is more general and requires no background knowledge of Greek myth in order to be understood. On the other hand it is less explicitly giving an order to other people that *they* must keep the speaker bound to his or her task, irrespective of any later pleas.

Answer (score 3):

IRREVOCABLE -- I'm even surprised this discussion is going on at such length.  The answer here seems clear.  In many countries there is a legal instrument called an 
                              IRREVOCABLE POWER OF ATTORNEY
often given, say, by a property owner to a trusted family member when the owner has to travel afar before consummation of a sale.  The holder of the Irrevocable PA has absolute legal right to attend to that sale in any manner s/he sees fit, and holds that power absolutely until the property is sold.  Then when it IS sold, (obviously) the power ceases only when the condition that required its execution is gone..

Comment: +1 Interesting. I think there are some typos in your answer. Do you mind..? :)

Comment: @NVZ--well, that's embarrassing!  Thank you for the heads-up.  I fixed the typos.

Answer (score 3):

I might use the phrase "**self binding**," but Wikipedia (quoted above) uses "**[Ulysses Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_pact)**" or "**advance directive**." I've also heard "**burning your ships**" as a common figurative phrase referring to Captain Hernán Cortés who scuttled his ships when landing in Mexico to ensure that they could not turn back.  This is a little different than "burning one's bridges" because the latter has more to do with one's relationships with others than things one has done to oneself to bind one's own future behavior.

"**Backing oneself up against a cliff**" was also an early example highlighted in [**this Radiolab episode** on self-binding mechanisms](http://www.radiolab.org/story/117165-help/).  They use "**Ulysses contract**" as the official name for this strategy.  They cite other examples too, like a pact whereby one person puts up money to a repulsive cause, to be donated if they do the thing they don't want themselves to do.

Another pop-culture example of this is in what Dumbledore says to Harry Potter in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* about the Emerald Potion/Potion of Despair (film clip [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nVQPwH2m4s)).

Answer (score 2):

You're making *a pact* with them or yourself.

**pact**, noun –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=pact%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> a formal agreement between individuals or parties.

*We both went on a diet and made a pact where each of us had to pay the other $5 if we were caught cheating.*

Answer (score 2):

You're putting [***safeguards***](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/safeguard) in place

> safeguard
>
> *noun* something that serves as a protection or defense or that ensures safety.
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/safeguard)
>
> *That is why it is necessary to put in safeguards to ensure that the development guidelines are respected by all governments.*
>
> [Reverso](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/garde-fou)